# Finding the covariance

Tags: statistics

Can you help me find the covariance of $\mathrm{Cov}(5X+3Y, 7X-Y)$  I've been looking up formulas all day and I can not find on that adds both x and y just constants.  Thank you!
$Mx=2, My=7, \mathrm{Var}X=4, \mathrm{Var} Y=9$, and $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=-2$

Comment: By $MX$, do you mean the expectation of $X$?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this would help: $$ \mathrm{Cov}\left(aX+bY, cW+dV\right) = ac~ \mathrm{Cov} (X,W) + ad~ \mathrm{Cov}(X,V) +bc~\mathrm{Cov}(Y,W)+ bd~\mathrm{Cov}(Y,V)$$ for real valued random variables, $X,Y,V$ and $W$ and constants, $a,b,c,d$.

You would also find these helpful: $\mathrm{Cov}(X,X) = \mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathrm{Cov}(Y,X)$.

I think this is all you need to know to solve the problem. Let me know if you need additional help.